# Массив со сдвинутыми индексами на Си

Tags: c, массивы

Как на Си создать массив на 100 элементов, который имел бы индексы элементов от-77 до 22.

Comment: VladD, необходим другой способ решения задачи. Этот не устраивает преподавателя, который поставил эту задачу. Был предложен ему сразу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Например, возьмите обыкновенный массив на 100 элементов, и используете указатель на 77-ой элемент.

```
int vanilla_array[100];
int* shifted_array = &vanilla_array[77];
```

Теперь вы можете использовать `shifted_array` с индексами от `-77` до `22`.

Comment: Снимаю шляпу... :)

Comment: Эту задачу поставил преподаватель в институте. Такой вариант с указателем на 77 элемент был предложен ему сразу. Но его не устроил, т к далее идет обращение к элементам через указатель, а не через имя массива. Требует, чтобы именно индексы массива были от -77.

Comment: Ну передайте этот указатель в функцию с сигнатурой `void f(int[] data)`. Надеюсь, это убедит вашего преподавателя. Если только он не хочет от вас какое-нибудь идиотское решение, являющееся по стандарту undefined behaviour (это вполне вероятно, если преподаватель «старой закалки»).

Comment: Вариант с указателем прошел. Преподаватель хотел, чтобы я убедился в том, что другого способа нет или он не дает стабильного решения задачи. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @J.Bon: Ох :) Значит, была ловушка. Вот и хорошо.